# Embedded broker Active MQ start

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I wrote a little program that use activemq embedded broker. Program run on one machine successfully  but does not work another one. Both of server have sun os 10 & java 7 and also activemq 5.5.1. I mean with does not work, new BrokerService() constructor call does not return for a while (a couple of minutes). Snippet code is like below.

Thanks for advices..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // .... 
    try {
        p.start("tcp://192.168.4.2:61616");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // ....

}


public void start(String brokerAddress) throws MessagingException {
    try {

        System.out.println(">>> initialize 2");
        broker = new JmsBroker(brokerAddress, brokerAddress.substring(6));
        System.out.println(">>> initialize 3");
        broker.start();
        System.out.println(">>> initialize 4");


        messageProducer = new JmsProducer(brokerAddress,
                                          "MESSAGING_IF_NAME",
                                          false,
                                          5000);
        System.out.println(">>> initialize 5");

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}


public class JmsBroker extends Thread {

private BrokerService       broker;
private Object              lock;
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsBroker.class);
private String              connector;


public JmsBroker(String jmsAddress, String brokerName) throws MessagingException {
    broker = new BrokerService(); // !!!!! PROBLEM
    broker.setBrokerName(brokerName);
    broker.setUseJmx(true);
    broker.setUseLoggingForShutdownErrors(true);
    broker.setSchedulerSupport(false);
    broker.setPersistent(false);
    connector = jmsAddress;

    try {
        System.out.println(">>> s1");
        broker.addConnector(connector);
        System.out.println(">>> s2");
        broker.start(true);
        System.out.println(">>> s3");

        while (!broker.isStarted()) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            System.out.println("BROKER NOT STARTED");
        }

        logger.info("JMS BROKER STARTED");
        System.out.println("JMS BROKER STARTED");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new MessagingException(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MessagingException(e);
    }
}

public void run() {
    try {
        lock = new Object();
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.wait();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("", e);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What happends if you download amq stand alone dist. and simply run it? Will it still hang on start up? Maybe the logs will tell you some hint.

Comment: I am not pretty sure "Stand alone dist" means but if it means running "activemq start" command. It's works that does not hang on (but has some exceptions on logs).

Comment: Transport failed: java.net.SocketException: Invalid option or socket reset by remote peer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.web.filter.ApplicationContextFilter
FAILED spring: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.apache.activemq.web.filter.ApplicationContextFilter
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.apache.activemq.web.filter.ApplicationContextFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.util.FilenameGuardFilter
FAILED FilenameGuardFilter: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.apache.activemq.util.FilenameGuardFilter

Comment: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.apache.activemq.util.FilenameGuardFilter
Transport failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong record on etc/hosts file causes this problem. After removing problem is solved.